# CSS Frames, my content does not obey the frame limitations

Tags: css

I am trying to create a CSS Frame where I have a small left frame and a large right frame.

I want to put a logo and some misc links on the left.

I want to put navigation and content on the right.

When I add content to the left side it pushes the content on the right down to the lowest point. I used an example CSS frame page to start.

Here is an example link: http://6colors.co/test/

I want the Media Room and About links to be at the top of the right frame and I just don't see it.

An HTML snippet:

```
<!-- Left Frame -->
<div id="framecontentLeft">
    <div class="innertube">
        <header>  
        <hgroup>
        <div class="FloatingBox">
                    <h1>6&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="AppleGreen">C</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="AppleYellow">o</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="AppleOrange">l</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="AppleRed">o</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="ApplePurple">r</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="AppleBlue">s</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </h1>  

        <h2>
            A&nbsp;
            <span class="AppleBlue">Nostalgic</span>
            <span class="ApplePurple">Trip</span>
            <span class="AppleRed">Down</span>
            <span class="AppleOrange">Memory</span> 
            <span class="AppleYellow">Lane</span>.
        </h2>
        </div>

                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                <a class="AppleRed" href="#">Have Footage To Submit?</a>

        <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <a class="AppleRed" href="#">Need To Contact Us?</a>
    </hgroup>  
     </header>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Right Frame -->
<div id="maincontent">
    <div class="innertube">

    <?php include('includes/menu.inc'); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* v1.0 | 20080212 */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    /* vertical-align: baseline; */
    background: transparent;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 2;
    background-image: url('images/background.png');
    /*width: 90%; */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%; 
}

.framecontentLeft, .framecontentRight{
   position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 200px; /*Width of left frame div*/
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: navy;
color: white;
}

.framecontentRight{
left: auto;
right: 0; 
width: 150px; /*Width of right frame div*/
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: #fff;
color: #fff;
}

.maincontent{
position: absolute; 
top: 0;
left: 200px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
/*right: 150px; */ /*Set right value to WidthOfRightFrameDiv*/
bottom: 0;
overflow: auto; 
background: #fff;
}

.innertube{
   margin: 15px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each DIV (to provide padding)*/
}

* html body{ /*IE6 hack*/
    padding: 0 0 0 200px; /*Set value to (0 WidthOfRightFrameDiv 0 WidthOfLeftFrameDiv)*/
}

* html #maincontent{ /*IE6 hack*/
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how to fix this and achieve what I want?

Comment: please don't take offense, but the style is quite a mess, like that there is no way that it is ever going to work..

Comment: @Lucius - Well, I do have this in a number of includes, I just put it all together for demonstration purposes. CSS is obviously in its own file, etc.

Comment: If you're going to use HTML5 elements then you should probably use the HTML5 doctype and get rid of the quirks mode trigger.

Comment: What I meant by 'messy style' was not as much about the tidyness of the code, but more about some misconceptions behind it..  
maybe you need to study better css positioning and layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, do yourself a favour, and get rid of absolute positioning..
What you could do in this particular case, is to float left the side menu and keep the main content layer as a normal static positioned div, just adding an appropriate left margin.
See the example code below:

Markup:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidemenu">some content</div>
    <div id="maincontent">blah blah blah</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Style:

```
* { /* jolly selector '*' applies the following rules to all elements */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #CCC; /* whatever background you see fit */
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline; /* IE fix */
}
#sidemenu { /* this layer is floated LEFT */
    float: left;
    display: inline; /* IE fix */
    width: 200px;
    background: #DDD;
}
#maincontent { /* this layer is a plain fixed-position div */
    margin-left: 220px; /* the margin makes it align correctly with the left 'frame' */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I noticed was that you have `<div id="maincontent">` in the markup but .maincontent in the styling which would target `<div class="maincontent">`

I wouldn't use position absolute for this.